# FIND_IN_SET with like clause mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table where I am using comma separated values like:

```
user_name      books
abc            PHP,Java
xyz            Net,Shift,PHP
```

I can handle comma-separated value searching using the `FIND_IN_SET` function of MySQL.

Now books names are auto suggested means if any one search with keyword "J" , system should search and match the word **Java** and give result of user "abc".

I tried to use like clause with `FIND_IN_SET` but it's not working.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This article has a custom function for using wildcards with FIND_IN_SET: https://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=148

Comment: *"I tried to use like clause with FIND_IN_SET but its not working."* - Not knowing what the code looks like or the schema, it could be a while before you get a (possible) solution.

Comment: you should look into relation tables instead of using comma-separated values.

Comment: A schema like this is a clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Don't use comma-separated values. Do use proper one-to-many relational tables. MySQL can "handle" these values, but performance is abysmal on all but the smallest datasets.

Comment: hi @FunkFortyNiner I know its not right way but I did not create this schema , This was given to me and I have to make it work. I know I can create a new table for books name and search from this but if anything possible here ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution but you can use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `library` WHERE `books` LIKE 'J%' OR `books` LIKE '%,J%'
```